# How to find matching object for: -[CFArray _cfTypeID]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I got stuck by this error message because for three days I didn't find the object _cfTypeID neither the object's address noted after that message. I know that there must be an array that I access but it is already destroyed.

My iPhone app is based on a tab bar controller and with one tab I switch to a new view controller which creates a navigation view controller and hide the whole tab bar controller from being accessed. I've chosen this way because the whole tab bar view logic runs in portrait orientation while the navigation view controller does its job in landscape orientation.

The first run is always fine when it starts with any portrait view via tab bar, changing to the landscape view of the navigation view controller. I have three views pushed on the navigation stack. On the first run there is also no crash when I navigate back to the root controller, leave this on and get back to the tab bar controller's last visible view. At that point the navigation view controller gets deallocated.

The crash happens on the second run, navigating again from the tab bar controller to the navigation view controller down to the third pushed view controller. At that point the navigation view controller and its three view controllers on stack are recreated. The crash happens when I leave the bottom most view on the stack either by pressing the backBarButton or the rightBarButton which I have created as a Done button.

I've not yet found where I'm not fine with the memory management as I don't have an array that's called _cfTypeID myself nor do I access this array directly. GDB goes crashing during a call to synchronize of NSUserDefaults which I use in viewWillDisappear of the view that just gets off screen. Instruments with the Leaks tool terminates the process after this crash and its messages are not helpful for me.

...and there is a difference of behaviour between running in the simulator and on the device (which is iPhone 4): on the device I can pop one more view controller from the navigation view controller and get the crash when leaving the view by the backBarButton.

I've decided not to post any code lines because there is lots of it and might not make sense to put it right in here. But I can supply parts of it if needed. I'll be glad for hints to tools I can use to identify either the broken array or anything else to revise my memory management (which is of course not perfect as I'm quite new to objc coming from c++ and php).

Cheers,
Konran

Comment: The error is definitely related to an array you implemented and did not have enough retains. It's especially common if you implemented an autorelease array and forgot that you'll need it later on. Try using debugger/tools to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is that none of the arrays I own has a name _cfTypeID ... I simply can't find any reference of that name. So, up to now all debugger/instruments activities failed. I nslogged all view controller instances, arrays and dictionaries with address and retain count after creation and just before I destroy the navigation view controller. It all looks good (retain count 2, navigation view controller 3) except the first view controller pushed on the stack with **[self.theCtrl pushViewController:viewControl animated:NO];** which has a retain count of 27 and 2 before I destroy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_cfTypeId` is not the name of the array, it's the name of the message being sent to an instance of `CFArray`. The specific error is coming from somewhere inside the framework code which is why you don't recognize anything about it, but the cause is that something in your code is either not retaining something it should be, is releasing something that it shouldn't, or is prematurely releasing something that it still wants to be using.

BTW, don't use `retainCount`, it doesn't work like you think and is generally useless.

Comment: Ok, that fills some light into it ... even if I didn't find it yet. It really seems to be within the one view controller where the crash is initialized when I press any of the navigation bar buttons. I moved some view controllers around on the stack and inserted/appended a dummy and it's always the same one where it dies. I'll keep on research...

Comment: Thanks, found it. Please see the code below as here is no proper formatting possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, very strange - but here it is:

```
- (void)loadPrefs
{
NSUserDefaults* prefs  = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray* tmpArr = nil;

// initialize currency name color array
if ((tmpArr = (NSMutableArray*)[diagView loadPrefsColorArray:@"diagCellColors"]) != nil)
    self.cellColors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tmpArr];
else
    self.cellColors = [diagView defaultCellColors];

tmpArr = nil;   //+++ added this to release tmpArr

// initialize currency arrays
if ((tmpArr = [prefs objectForKey:@"diagUsedCurrencies"]) != nil)
    self.arrCurrencies = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tmpArr];
else
    self.arrCurrencies = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];

tmpArr = nil;   //+++ added this to release tmpArr
...
```

In my original code I had set tmpArr to nil only before returning from this method. In fact I don't understand why it is necessary to reset tmpArr as I keep my own reference retained (as in self.cellColors which is a retaining property). I have similar contructions in almost all of my view controllers and only in one case I've got this undefined crash.

Comment: Assigning nil there doesn't actually release anything. I'd guess that at some point tmpArr is being left with its old value rather than being assigned to what you think it should be. They you release it, accidentally releasing that old value (which is probably something that is already autoreleased).

Comment: Thanks Anomie. Anyway it seems odd for me that it happens to accidentally releasing the old value ... self.cellColors is invoked by the setter method synthesized and so retained once by its property. I don't understand why the second assignment to tmpArr (w/out resetting its value to nil) can release the old value. Hmm. Anyway I'll keep continuing to solve it like I did.

Comment: There are no accidents in code... more likely than not, you've just moved the problem and it'll start crashing mysteriously in the future, only there will be more code and more complexity to deal with.  Did you try using NSZombies or the other tools for tracking down this exact kind of problem?

Comment: bbum, that sounds worse than expected. I have NSZombieEnabled in my project as long as it is not finished. I've cleaned up the code due to the static analyzer's output and with the Instruments Leaks tool and GDB of course. The thing here happened after the cleanup ... when I learned that viewDidUnload was never called and so nothing was deallocated. I changed things so that dealloc properly removes my data vars - and doing it I learned that many of my data vars and view controllers retained too much. Now they don't and release properly. The crash only came after constructing my views 2nd time.